# passive form in a long sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, passive-voice, formal-language

The original passive sentence (word1..word10 are represent a long piece of a sentence:

```
 Results that show word1 word2 word3 word4.. word10, are obtained.
```

But in this sentence a verb (obtained) at the end of a long sentence—make it hard to read.

Which of the options below of passive sentences is a legal better formal English (or suggest other formal passive sentence options):

```
1) It is obtained results that show word1 word2 word3 word4.. word10.
```

or

```
2) Results are obtained that show word1 word2 word3 word4.. word10.
```

(An active sentence option that is not considered in that question: We obtain results..)

Comment: "It is obtained results" is not grammatical and doesn't make sense.

Comment: It is very confusing to write "word1 word2..."   It would be far far better to give us you actual example.  What do you have to hide?

Comment: 2 is correct, but very technical sounding. "The obtained results show: ...." isn't identical in meaning, but likely includes the original intended meaning.

Comment: In context, "obtain" is probably unnecessary. E.g., "Twenty university sophomores were surveyed about X. The results show that . . ." This pattern is common in academic writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence 2 is good: it exhibits [heavy-constituent extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition), which is quite common in technical writing.

Your 1 is understandable, but I don't think any native English speaker would write it.

3. There are results obtained that show ...

is also possible.

Comment: @Lambie: you're right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: No, worries. :)